# Rails - I cannot read the contents of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am having an issue trying to read the contents of a rails array. (ruby 2.x, rails 4.x)

I have a search form where one of the items is a select multiple. The array is stored in a text field called category. I am getting the array with

```
 <%= f.select :category,
                       options_for_select(@categories.sort),
                       {:include_blank => true},
                       {:multiple => true, :size =>10}  %>
```

If I do a <%= @search.inspect %> I get something like

> Search id: 675, document_title: "", summary: "", owner: "[\"\"]", category:
>        "[\"\", \"Apples\", \"Calendar\", \"Forms\"]", file_name: "", created_at: 
>       "2015-12-28 13:57:45", updated_at: "2015-12-28 13:57:45", doc_to_email: nil

I see that the category field has an array with the three items I selected.

If I do <%= @search.category %>  I see

> ["", "Apples", "Calendar", "Forms"]

So far, it seems to me that the array is there.

However,

```
<%= @search.category[0..8] %>
```

results in

> ["", "App

```
<%= @search.category.first %>
```

> [

```
<%= @search.category.last %>
```

> ]

Which was not what I was expecting

```
<% @search.category.each do |cat_name| %>"
     <%=  cat_name %>
<% end %>
```

results in an error of

> Showing
>   C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/technical_library/app/views/searches/show.html.erb
>   where line #85 raised:
>
> undefined method `each' for "[\"\", \"Apples\", \"Calendar\",
>   \"Forms\"]":String Rails.root:
>   C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/td
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/searches/show.html.erb:85:in
>   `_app_views_searches_show_html_erb___938985047_80352240'

What am I doing wrong in trying to read the contents of the array?

Comment: it's not an array, it is a string with the contents of an array inside it.

Comment: If you look at it again, you'll see that @search.category contains a *string* that looks like your array, not an array.  When you ask for `[0..8` you're asking for the first 9 characters which is precisely what it's showing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models' `category` is a string, not an array.

To store array in a text field - add

```
serialize :category, JSON
```

into model.